# "Wrong number or types of argument in call to '>'" when comparing dates in PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Here's my code. Why am I getting here that exception? It's of the same type! `mitarbeitergehalt.gueltigab = DATE.`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fu_gehalt_am(p_maID IN mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterid%TYPE
                                       ,p_Date IN mitarbeitergehalt.gueltigab%TYPE)
RETURN NUMBER AS
  v_gehalt mitarbeitergehalt.gehalt%TYPE DEFAULT 0;
BEGIN
  FOR v_dates IN (SELECT gueltigab
                  FROM mitarbeitergehalt
                  WHERE mitarbeiterid = p_maID
                  ORDER BY 1)      
  LOOP
    IF v_dates > p_Date THEN <--------------------------------------- HERE!!
      SELECT gehalt
      INTO v_gehalt
      FROM mitarbeitergehalt
      WHERE v_dates = gueltigab AND mitarbeiterid = p_maID;

      RETURN gehalt;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN 0;
END;
/
```

Comment: What is th definition of the table `mitarbeitergehalt`?

Comment: It should be `IF v_dates.gueltigab > p_Date` as `v_dates` is a cursor variable not a DATE variable,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your original problem, here is the fixed code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fu_gehalt_am(p_maID IN mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterid%TYPE
                                       ,p_Date IN mitarbeitergehalt.gueltigab%TYPE)
RETURN NUMBER AS
  v_gehalt mitarbeitergehalt.gehalt%TYPE DEFAULT 0;
BEGIN
  FOR v_dates IN (SELECT gueltigab
                  FROM mitarbeitergehalt
                  WHERE mitarbeiterid = p_maID
                  ORDER BY 1)      
  LOOP
    IF v_dates.gueltigab > p_Date THEN <----------- HERE!!
      SELECT gehalt
      INTO v_gehalt
      FROM mitarbeitergehalt
      WHERE v_dates.gueltigab = gueltigab AND mitarbeiterid = p_maID;  <--- and here

      RETURN v_gehalt;  <------ and here.
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN 0;
END;
/
```

But I think you can simplify it by using `select into` and `DENSE_RANK FIRST` instead of loops:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fu_gehalt_am(p_maID IN mitarbeiter.mitarbeiterid%TYPE
                                       ,p_Date IN mitarbeitergehalt.gueltigab%TYPE)
RETURN NUMBER AS
  v_gehalt mitarbeitergehalt.gehalt%TYPE DEFAULT 0;
BEGIN
    select coalesce(max(gehalt) over (dense_rank first order by gueltigab), 0)
    into v_gehalt
    from mitarbeitergehalt
    where mitarbeiterid = p_maID
        and gueltigab > p_Date;
    return v_gehalt;
END;
/
```